# Should I use mongoose sort or pipes to implement my own?

Tags: angular, mean-stack

Sort features are not included in angular 2. I can use mongoose sort and is working in my shopping-cart application. Should I use pipes instead? What are the drawbacks? I am still new to angular 2 and mean stack. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used both pipes and mongoose queries in my application. This is to
sort the `category(ele, sh, vid)` while `Product` component sorts 
the searched products alphabetically by mongoose at `OnInit()`.

```
<div [ngClass]="displayCategory">
  <ul *ngFor="let category of categories | order by: ['fieldName'];let i=index">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value={category.selected}}
        [ngModel]="category.selected" (change)="onCategory($event,i)">
        {{category.fieldName}}{{category.count()}})
     </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```